# Core Plot set custom label for y axis

Tags: ios, core-plot

i'm new at using Core Plot.
So what i actually want is to set custom labels for the y axis like using an array with different activities like volleyball, soccer and swimming and to this the x axis has dates. Implement the date array to Core Plot was no problem, but now i want, like i told, to have an custom y axis and for every activity i want to show a horizontal bar with the time that soccer or another takes. The Bar Chart should show me which time an activity takes, like soccer starts at 08:00 am and ends 11:00.

i hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone` labeling policy for the y-axis and create your own axis labels with the desired label text. There are several demos in the *Plot Gallery* example app including the labeling policy and the bar chart in the composite plot.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
The yAxis labels are customized as i need them

The next problem is to plot the data to my view. My code shows the bar for "soccer" beginning at 2nd december and is 4 days long to 6th december, as i want, but it fits not to the yAxis and also there are plots for the other days with a day of 0 so on each day there is a bar with day 0.

Could you give me an code for plot an bar, which y-value is positioned on "Soccer" and it's x-value begins at 02nd december with length 4 days as example?Sry, but i have no idea how to build that code, even after looking into your CorePlotGallery.

Comment: In your datasource, give the "Soccer" bar a location that corresponds with the axis label, a base value of 2 December, and a tip value of 6 December. Be sure to set `barBasesVary` to `YES` if different bars will have different base values.

Comment: Thank you! I'm generating the difference between the 2 dates and use this value as offset, works great!